# Convert R matrix like `m<-rbind(c("x/(z+1)","x^2/(z+1)"),c("y/(z+1)","y^2/(z+1)"))` to table it to .doc

Tags: latex, r-markdown, symbolic-math, doc

I want to insert R matrix like `m<-rbind(c("x/(z+1)","x^2/(z+1)"),c("y/(z+1)","y^2/(z+1)"))` as a table in R Markdown than knit it to .doc.
I would like it in a neat form, such that all cells are separated by lines and all formulas displayed properly. *I want to do it automatically from matrix I have.* 
I am thinking about thous formulas inside the matrix as simple examples of any formula that contains variables and arithmetic operations.
First I tried with more simple expression `m<-rbind(c("x","x^2"),c("y","y^2"))`
with no result.

**TeXForm(m)**

```
library(Ryacas)
Sym(m)
TeXForm(m)
```

I got:

```
"$x$";
```

**pander(m)**

I got:

```
-------
 A   B 
--- ---
 x  x^2 

 y  y^2
-------
```

formulas in cells were displayed not properly.

**knitr::kable(m)**

I got:

```
|A  |B   |
|:--|:---|
|x  |x^2 |
|y  |y^2 |
```

It wasn`t displayed properly in .doc.

**xtable(m)**

I got LaTeX code which I was unable to knit in .doc. But when knitted in pdf formulas in cells were displayed not properly. I also tried `print(xtable(m),type="html")`
 I wasn`t able to knit it to .doc, but in html document it gives results similar to previous.

**Replace each element of matrix with LaTeX code**

```
Apymtx<-function(m,f){m1<-m 
for (k in 1:nrow(m)){ for (l in 1:ncol(m)){m1[k,l]<-f(m[k,l])}}
return(m1)}
m<-Apymtx(m, TeXForm)
```

I got:

```
[,1]               [,2]                
[1,] "( TeXForm( x ) )" "( TeXForm( x^2 ) )"
[2,] "( TeXForm( y ) )" "( TeXForm( y^2 ) )"
```

Than I tried to change 'class' of TeXForm(m[1,1]) to 'character' with no result.

**How to get table filed with formulas in R Markdown, and knit it to .doc?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss that `pandoc` interprets [Tex formulas between the dollar signs](http://pandoc.org/README.html#math). E.g.:

```
> pander(data.frame(
+   A = c("$x^2$", "$\\frac{x}{y}$"),
+   B = c("$\\sum_{1}^{n}foobar_i$",
+         "$\\cos (2\\theta) = \\cos^2 \\theta - \\sin^2 \\theta$")))

--------------------------------------
      A                  B            
------------- ------------------------
    $x^2$      $\sum_{1}^{n}foobar_i$ 

$\frac{x}{y}$ $\cos (2\theta) = \cos^2
              \theta - \sin^2 \theta$ 
--------------------------------------
```

Renders fine in `docx`:

[image]

---

**Edit**: based on the question update that made it clearer for me that you want to transform the math formulas to TeX by `Ryacas`, please see this approach to do so. Unfortunately, I could not get the `retclass="unquote"` argument working in `yacas`, that's why the ugly string manipulation:

```
> pander(apply(m, c(1, 2), function(x) gsub('\\"|;| ', '', yacas(TeXForm(x))$YacasForm)))

--------------- -------------------
$\frac{x}{z+1}$ $\frac{x^{2}}{z+1}$

$\frac{y}{z+1}$ $\frac{y^{2}}{z+1}$
--------------- -------------------
```

MS Word output after calling `pander`:

[image]

Comment: I was considering thous "x", "y", "x^2", "y^2" as simplest examples of any mathematical equations inside the matrix. Sorry, I should have made them more complicated. Imagine If there were more things like x/(z+1), x^2/(z+1), y/(z+1), y^2/(z+1).

Comment: @AlexAlex I've added some further examples to my answer, but believe me -- a one liner should have been enough to answer your question: add the dollar signs and learn about the TeX math syntax :)

Comment: OK. But it is by hand. One part of the problem is how to do it automatically from given matrix.

Comment: @AlexAlex the above markdown table was generated from a `data.frame`. What do you mean by "automatically"? If transforming e.g. `1/2` to the correct TeX format as `\frac{1}{2}`, you might be in trouble. But please edit the question to briefly include what you really need, like sharing the matrix you have.

Comment: For example, my matrix is called 'm', I do with it A(m); B(m); C(m) ... , where A(), B() and C() are R commands without paying attention to it`s content. Imagine if there were many similar or one big matrix, then it is weary unpleasant to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variant of solution based on answer marked as correct.

```
library(Ryacas)
library(pander)
m<-rbind(c("x","x^2"),c("y","y^2"))
Apycs<-function(m){
library(Ryacas)
m1<-m 
for (k in 1:nrow(m)){ for (l in 1:ncol(m)){
m.2<-yacas(TeXForm(m[k,l]))[[2]]
m1[k,l]<-substr(m.2,2,nchar(m.2)-2)}}
return(m1)}
m<-Apycs(m)
pander(m)
```